# working with name in html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<select name="websites" size="1">
                <option selected>Select</option>
                <option  value="#GENERAL MEDICINE">General Medicine</option>
                <option value="#CARDIOLOGY">Cardiology</option>
                <option value="#PAEDIATRICS">Paediatrics</option>
                <option value="#NEUROLOGY">Neurology</option>
        <option value="#GASTROENTEROLOGY">Gastroenterology</option>
<input type="button" value="Go!"
                onClick="location=document.testform.websites.options
                [document.testform.websites.selectedIndex].value">

<a name="GENERAL MEDICINE">GENERAL MEDICINE</a>
```

But it's not working.

I create a web page that having labels like General Medicine, Cardiology, Paediatrics like that these labels are defining their consultant list.
So that i get one combo box when i select General Medicine or other item from combo box  the focus goes to selected item but the above code is not working

Comment: What isn't working? In what way? What's going wrong?

Comment: Please expand the question. This is hopelessly vague. What is the table structure? What is the exact query?

Comment: what is not working? what is supposed to happen, and in response to what?

Answer (score 1):

add an ID attribute and change your onclick event :

```
<select name="websites" id="websites" size="1">
                <option selected>Select</option>
                <option  value="#GENERAL MEDICINE">General Medicine</option>
                <option value="#CARDIOLOGY">Cardiology</option>
                <option value="#PAEDIATRICS">Paediatrics</option>
                <option value="#NEUROLOGY">Neurology</option>
        <option value="#GASTROENTEROLOGY">Gastroenterology</option>
<input type="button" value="Go!"
                onClick="location=document.getElementById('websites').options
                [document.testform.websites.selectedIndex].value">

<a name="GENERAL MEDICINE">GENERAL MEDICINE</a>
```

See example : http://jsfiddle.net/uv7w9/

Comment: No need for an ID, just use `this`: `onClick="location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value"`

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have enclosed your html code inside FORM tag because your javascript refers to `document.testform`

```
<form name="testform">
```

Check working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ekszD/).